# Android: how to make text (String type, method addCellText) as a hyperlink?

Tags: android, text, hyperlink

I have the table and add in the first column of some data (String type, method addCellText(LinearLayout row, float weight, String **text**)). How to make this **text** as a hyperlink?
Best regards!

Comment: what u have tried so far ?

Comment: Use CustomListView

Answer (score 0):

The method **addCellText**(LinearLayout row, float weight, String text) return TextView. Therefore, I can to make TextView as a hyperlink:

```
TextView someData = addCellText(row, 2, someStringValue);
someData.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
String text = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>" + someStringValue + "</a>";
someData.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```